# how can I edit a flutter "barcode_scan 1.0.0" plugin

Tags: flutter

I'm using the "barcode_scan 1.0.0" plugin that is available in dartlang (this is the link: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan). Now the question, I want to know if anyone knows how to edit the screen when the camera appears ready to read codes:

1) I need to add an appbar with a title.

2) I need to block the automatic screen rotation.

3) I would like you to read codes at 90 degrees. A red bar is also included but at 90 degrees.

I will thank you very much if you can guide me to solve the problem.

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can't with that package because it won't provides you with a way to fit a reader widget in your widget tree (its just calling a native API).

Based on your requirements, you can use some of the other available packages with the same purpose. I can name you a few that support being placed on your widget tree:

- [fast_qr_reader_view](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_qr_reader_view)
- [qr_mobile_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_mobile_vision)
- [flutter_mobile_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mobile_vision)